How to use CMR font in Lualatex/Xelatex
How to use CMR font family in text and math in Lualatex and Xelatex. I need same font appearance and its name which appears in pdf generated using dvi to ps and ps to pdf.

Welcome to TeX.SE. CMR is one of a standard font family, can you provide a MWE for your code?

Computer Modern is an 8-bit font and is therefore unsuitable for use with a Unicode engine - can you explain a bit more about your requirements?

Is there any particular reason thta you want to use CMR and not LM or NCM?

latin modern is the default for luatex and is essentially the same design as cm, why use a unicode tex if you are going to use a 7-bit font with only 126 characters so only ascii and not even european accented letters?

@DavidCarlisle But if you run lualatex you do not by default get Unicode math, do you?

@mickep Not at the present time - it's on the agenda
